# Are Christians consciously aware of the first time they received the Holy Spirit?

Tags: pneumatology, comparative-christianity, spirituality, demographics, born-again

I don't know if there are statistics on this, or if the answer depends on the denomination, but are Christians usually consciously aware of the first time they received the Holy Spirit? Is the reception of the Holy Spirit for the first time an unmistakable, life-changing, [self-evident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-evidence) experience/event that most Christians can easily remember, the date of which they can easily pinpoint on a calendar?

I'm interested in an **overview of Christian viewpoints** on these questions.

---

Related denomination survey questions:

- [Do all believers receive the Holy Spirit at conversion but only a few are filled with the Holy Spirit post conversion?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/79507/50422)
- [What denominations practice "laying on of hands" so that new converts may receive the Holy Ghost, and what manifestations are usually expected?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/91868/50422)

Related hermeneutical question:

- [Is Paul implying in Acts 19:2 that the reception of the Holy Spirit for the first time is a self-evident experience for the new believer?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/77330/38524)

Comment: This is not an answer but a confession that I was made powerfully aware of the Holy Spirit shortly after my baptism. It was an immediate and powerful response to a group prayer that I would receive confirmation from the Holy Spirit. Some Christians experience this, many do not. As for statistics, or an overview of Christian opinions, good luck with that.  Statistics are meaningless when it comes to how the Holy Spirit operates. He comes and goes as He pleases in His work of convicting the world of sin and turning people to God in heartfelt repentance. The evidence is in a transformed life.

Comment: Because reception of the Holy Spirit is not viewed as some kind of competition (except, perhaps, in those denominations that set such store by such an experience that they claim "you cannot be a true Christian" without it) no statistics are kept. Beware any group that expects members to testify to some kind of sensation or experience of a supernatural kind when the Bible tells us that he convicts us of sin, to bring us to repentance and spiritual life which - in itself - is a miracle akin to creation. If that isn't good enough evidence of his working, I don't know what is.

Comment: It is hard to imagine someone going from death unto life and not noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you part from the Catholic/Orthodox or from the Protestant concept:

According to the [Roman Catholic](https://www.catholic.com/qa/we-receive-the-holy-spirit-at-baptism) and [Orthodox](https://orthochristian.com/139979.html) dogmatics, the Holy Spirit is received in the Baptism, and in the Roman Catholic Church, small children are baptised. The children are of cause not consciously receiving the Holy Spirit. Accepting the Catholic and Orthodox approach, most Christians receive the Holy Spirit unconsciously. Only converts who receive the baptim in a more mature age may receive the Holy Spirit consciously.

[Lutheran](https://www.lcms.org/about/beliefs/faqs/doctrine) and Reformed churches also baptise small children but there are no dogmatics that the small children receive the Holy Spirit in this baptism (the reformed church refuses dogmatics in general). Rather, the reception of the Holy Spirit is seen as a gift, received through [grace of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_gratia). Luther as well as the Reformed Theologian Karl Barth say "only through the Grace of God". The contribution of the believer is only the will of the person to receive the Holy Spirit (Mt. 7:7 "Ask, and you will be given").

The believer can be concious of the reception Holy Spirit. It is also accepted that a believer receives the Holy Spirit unconciously.

The way the reception Holy Spirit is perceived is very individual. Many members born into a Protestant family do not feel to have received the Holy Spirit in a precise moment of their lives but rather to have accepted the belief in a longer process. Evangelical Churches often also encourage a concious event where a decided conversion or reversion may be linked to.

The general answer on the question is "sometimes but not always".

Answer (score 3):

I would say no, based on experience. I know people who had immediate, major changes in their life at the time of salvation and others who did not.

**Timing**. Part of the confusion is that different denominations teach different models for salvation. If the Holy Spirit comes to a person at a time or manner at odds with what their denomination teaches, they might not make the connection. They may have had the experience, noticed it, but discounted it as something else because they are conditioned to do so.

**Emotion versus reality**. The saved person is changed in many ways: morality, ethics, emotional life, actions, sense of identity, deepending relationship to the Body of Christ... The Holy Spirit performs radical surgery on a person. The emotional response to being saved and other, less flashy things may occur at different times. It took me years of self reflection coupled with a study of God's plan of salvation to pinpoint when my character and decision making process began to reflect the Holy Spirit's influence. The new evidence I found pointed to a time a year before I experienced the joy of salvation. I was suffering a profound depression at the time I was saved. Acting in faith and making unselfish decisions came long before the happy feelings.

Comment: " I know people who had immediate, major changes in their life at the time of salvation and others who did not" How do these people know they were saved, if they had no major changes in their life at the time of salvation?

Comment: 1 John and James give good tests that a person may apply to their self to determine if they are saved. The assurance of salvation is not based on feelings or works but on faith in the work of Christ.

Comment: Can you give a bit more specific of references?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather All of 1st John is written so that those who believe may know that they have eternal life.  It is, if you will, the epistle of assurance.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, but not all the time.

Many Christians can point to specific, powerful spiritual experiences in their lives, though it need not necessarily be the first time in their lives they were influenced by the Holy Ghost.

From a Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints perspective, former church President Ezra Taft Benson taught:

> The scriptures record remarkable accounts of men whose lives changed
> dramatically, in an instant, as it were: Alma the Younger, Paul on the
> road to Damascus, Enos praying far into the night, King Lamoni. Such
> astonishing examples of the power to change even those steeped in sin
> give confidence that the Atonement can reach even those deepest in
> despair.
>
> But we must be cautious as we discuss these remarkable examples.
> Though they are real and powerful, they are the exception more than
> the rule. For every Paul, for every Enos, and for every King Lamoni,
> there are hundreds and thousands of people who find the process of
> repentance much more subtle, much more imperceptible. Day by day they
> move closer to the Lord, little realizing they are building a godlike
> life. They live quiet lives of goodness, service, and commitment. They
> are like the Lamanites, who the Lord said “were baptized with fire and
> with the Holy Ghost, and they knew it not.” (3 Ne. 9:20)([source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1989/10/a-mighty-change-of-heart?lang=eng))

Sometimes experiences with the Holy Ghost (first time or otherwise) are overwhelming, obvious, and unmistakable. Others are quiet and gradual. Sometimes the influence & effects of the Holy Ghost are only evident in hindsight (e.g. Luke 24:32).

A useful analogy is the growth of a large tree. Watching it in real time the growth is virtually imperceptible. But over the course of a few decades the transformation is unmistakable: the tree we're looking at today is different from the tree a few decades prior.

My own experience is that the effects of the Holy Ghost upon people tend towards a gradual, gentle influence occasionally punctuated by dramatic, memorable experiences.